# Is it okay to use POST method than GET?

Tags: ajax, http, http-post, http-get

I do know for getting information from sever we use `GET` and for posting information we use `POST`. Now I have a search box where users can search for queries, But I'm using `POST` method for my search, say: user typed `avatar 4 release date`, and what I do is to take text box value, send it to server using ajax with `type='post'` and respond the result. As I suppose I should be using `GET` because i'm requesting information and am not posting.

So I was wondering is it okay to use `post` in my condition? Would I get any performance issue or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

> Some other notes on GET requests:
>
> - GET requests can be cached
> - GET requests remain in the browser history
> - GET requests can be bookmarked
> - GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
> - GET requests have length restrictions
> - GET requests should be used only to retrieve data

and POST:

> Some other notes on POST requests:
>
> - POST requests are never cached
> - POST requests do not remain in the browser history
> - POST requests cannot be bookmarked
> - POST requests have no restrictions on data length

Answer (score 0):

ys you can do with POST
ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            url: "search_file.php",
             type:"POST",
            data : {serach_text:$('#text_input').val()},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result){
    }});
```

'#text_input' is the id of search input
in php code you can access search_text with `$_POST['serach_text']`